# Shiny-server run as non-root does not find .my.cnf file

Tags: r, ubuntu-12.04, init, rstudio, shiny-server

I am running shiny-server as non-root (using my own user name) using an init script on ubuntu for security reasons. Unfortunately doing this seems to break my mysql connection (I use .my.cnf in my home directory). The file has rw permission for the owner (me).

It works fine from within RStudio and when running shiny-server as root.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: Find a way to have a test Shiny server app show where it thinks `Sys.getenv("HOME")` is and who `Sys.info()[["user"]]` is to make sure it's really running where and as who you expect.

Comment: You didn't specify how you're making the connection, but you can also specify which `.my.cnf` via the `default.file` option to `dbConnect()`

Comment: Thanks for the help. `Sys.getenv` revealed that `"HOME"` wasn't set. Setting it however, didn't help, but using the `default.file` option did the trick. Still don't quite get why changing the user running the process changes the system settings.